# npm semantic versioning in package.json - does it work only from version 1.0.0 and up?

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I noticed that even though I have specified version `^0.5.5` of [v-calendar](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar) library, and as of today version `0.6.3` is available, when I run `npm update`, the package is not updated.

When I test the version `^0.5.5` in [npmsemver](https://semver.npmjs.com/) calculator, only version `0.5.5` is in green, meaning that npm ignores versions `0.6.x` and up.

**Am I correct in assuming that semantic versioning with npm works only if the package is on version `1.0.0` and up?**

[npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning) specify that:

> If a project is going to be shared with others, it should start at 1.0.0, (though some projects on npm don't follow this rule).

but I couldn't find anything there saying that semantic versioning won't work if you release a package starting at version `0.x.x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004

The caret range is keyed on the left most non-zero value. This conforms with the common practice of shifting the SemVer rules one field to the right for experimental versions (0.y.z) such that the Y field is incremented for known breaking changes and the Z field is used for new features and bug fixes.  It is an historical artifact that should be eliminated from the standard in my opinion.